# Why angular scope hold reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

**JS**

```
angular.module('bindExample', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.gridFields = {
        id: {
            width: 50
        },
        price: {
            width: 60
        },
    };
    $scope.allData = {
        'one': {
            id: '1234qwe',
            price: 900
        },
        'two': {
            id: 'asdadw',
            price: 1700
        },
        'three': {
            id: '342sdaw',
            price: 1200
        },
    };
    $scope.edit = function(row) {
        console.log(row);
        $scope.buffer = $scope.allData[row];
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="bindExample">
   <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(row, data) in allData">
               <td ng-repeat="(field, option) in gridFields" ng-bind="data[field]"></td>
               <td><button ng-click="edit(row)">edit</button></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
         <input type='text' ng-model="buffer.id"/>
      </div>
      <div>
         <input type='text' ng-model="buffer.price"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After click on edit, values go to $scope.buffer variable from $scope.allData, and the inputs use the buffer as model, but when input is change the values in allData variable changing as well, but i don't want this, this is why is try to pass the values to other...

Problem illustrated here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b4hrj5uv/1/)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
    $scope.buffer = angular.copy($scope.allData[row]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First things, you're going to get unexpected results in `ng-repeat` if you use a parent `object` literal rather than an array (Angular doesnt guarantee that it will iterate through keys in order):

```
$scope.allData = [ //you're better off using an Array
            'one': {
                id: '1234qwe',
                price: 900
            },
            'two': {
                id: 'asdadw',
                price: 1700
            },
            'three': {
                id: '342sdaw',
                price: 1200
            },
        ]; //see above
```

Secondly, the reason this is happening is that Javascript copies **everything** as a reference unless it is a primitive, so when you do this:

```
$scope.buffer = $scope.allData[row];
```

You're actually just storing a pointer to the original object `$scope.allData[row]` in `$scope.buffer`.

To do a "deep copy" yo ucan use angular.copy as suggested by @moncefHassein-bey in his answer.

Comment: i accept @moncefHassein-bey's answer because he was the first with the solution, but of corse thank you your tut. I will keep in mind!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript will hold reference if assigned data is either `function` or `object` or `array`.

It provides a great benifit to the developer in many ways . but if you wanna to remove reference you have to clone it.

using angular

```
$scope.buffer = angular.copy($scope.allData[row]);
```